# Use powershell to populate dialog box from another program

Tags: powershell, automation

I am writing a script to uninstall and reinstall a piece of software.

Annoyingly, you have to enter a password as part of the uninstall process. (i.e. the uninstaller pops up with a box, the user enters a password to continue)

I want to be able to detect the dialog box, and enter the password automatically - so the user doesn't have to do anything. I seem to remember there's a way to do this, but not sure how.

Comment: is it a custom uninstaller, does it have any sort of COM interface?

Comment: Not too sure - we're working a bit blind as we don't have any way of interfacing with it directly. I wondered if there is a way you can detect the window in PS (can do this) and then give the textbox focus (there's only a single textbox on the dialog) and use PS to send keystrokes

Comment: I'd have to guess that the 'dialog box' is the Windows UAC prompt; running as admin should cause the popup to not be needed in that case.

Comment: Nope - not the UAC prompt. It's the uninstaller for a bit of Checkpoint software. The code I put below works fine for a normal dialog - however I think checkpoint have been sneaky (or security conscious!) and they're catching sendkeys and blocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$app = get-process | where {$_.mainwindowtitle -match "Admin Password"} 

$processID = 0

foreach ($a in $app) {

        if ($a.id -gt $processID)
         {
        $processID = $a.id
    }

}

start-sleep -Milliseconds 500

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($processID)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("mypassword{ENTER}")
```

Works great inmy demo app. Trouble is the app I am trying to send the password to is protected from SendKeys.

D'oh. Back to the drawing board...