# Is there a way for powershell to fill in username and password in a dialog box?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to launch a program with powershell, which I can do.  But the program has a signon window pop up for user id and password.

Is there a way for powershell to enter the userid information in the field {TAB} then enter the password and {ENTER} so that the program can logon to the AS400 server?

I cannot seem to find a way for powershell to populate the dialog box. Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\BPCS.WS").WaitForExit()


$app = get-process | where {$_.mainwindowtitle -match "User"} 

$processID = 0

foreach ($a in $app) {

        if ($a.id -gt $processID)
         {
        $processID = $a.id
    }

}

start-sleep -Milliseconds 500
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use powershell to populate dialog box from another program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879744/use-powershell-to-populate-dialog-box-from-another-program)

Comment: I tried the edit, but same result.  The first line of code launches the program but after that, I can't get powershell to send a username or password to the dialog box that pops up.

Comment: I'd look at using a program like AutoIT to write a mouse / SendKeys automation tool to handle this.  Have you tried asking the developers in charge of this tool / program if there is an API you use use with Rest or Com?  They might have connection strings available for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work but is worth a try to use SendKeys.
As a starting point :

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
#start your app as in your question
#then give the focus to it 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("ws") #or user? you'll have to test this
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("$username"); 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{TAB}"); 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("$password"); 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{ENTER}");
```